# How to get data from only one table in relational tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I get data from only one table in relational tables in entity framework?
I had created two tables. One is `Classes` and other is `Students`, and classes has one-to-many students relationship, but when I try to get data, it returns data from students and from classes tables.

(`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Class_A4175BA8B7189ED27663CF9F9601DDF445EED57DA923B995D31056ABB560F13A`).

How can I remove this columnn?

Code:

```
TestDbEntities entities = new TestDbEntities();
dataGridView1.DataSource = entities.Students.ToList();
```

Comment: Sounds like lazy loading. Either disable lazy loading for the context, make `Students` collection non virtual or use no tracking query - `entities.Students.AsNoTracking().ToList();`

Comment: thanks dear, data does not show but column name is still there how can i hide/remove it

Comment: Well, then use the other options. For instance, `var entities = new TestDbEntities(); entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with entity framework but the object you have listed there is a proxy object

`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Class_A4175BA8B7189ED27663CF9F9601DDF445EED57DA923B995D31056ABB560F13A`

That's why it has that strange name. If you trace your database call I would think that the query is not joining to the class table. Instead the proxy is generated to enable lazy loading. So if you never touch the class object, it is never grabbed from the DB.